# When executing code, I receive a System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteReader:Connection property has not been initialized.' Error

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2022

I am fairly new to VB and I am in the process of developing a program that can pull information from a specific database and display the information in a generated XML file.

Whenever the export button is clicked and processed, I receive the System.InvaildOperationExecption error specified above.

I will post an example of my code below, but for security purposes some information has to be left out as it is sensitive.  I can say with the utmost certainty that this connection information is entered correctly.  I will place stars in place of the sensitive information.

I feel I have correctly declared my variables properly in order for this to correctly connect to the database to pull information, but I still receive this error to no avail.

I will appreciate any advice given on this as I am fairly new to coding and utilizing Microsoft SQL database connections.

Below is my code.

```
    Public Sub MakeExportButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MakeExportButton.Click
        Dim daDaysSince As Integer = 0
        Dim itemNumber As Integer
        Dim gotAtLeastOne As String = "N"
        Dim MDBConnectString = "Persist Security Info=False;User ID=***;Password=******;Initial Catalog=***_****;Data Source=***.***.*.***;"
        Dim dt As New DataTable("Customer")
        dt.Columns.Add("Index")
        dt.Columns.Add("CustomerNumber")
        dt.Columns.Add("CustomerName")
        
        Dim drow As DataRow
        Dim cn As New SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader
        Dim daRowInfo As String

        daRowInfo = ""

        Dim DaysSincetemp As Integer = 0


        DaysSincetemp = daDaysSince * -5
        'Default yesterday, but can change time period.
        'Dim yesterday As Date = Now.AddDays(-5)

        Dim Daysbefore As Date = Now.AddDays(DaysSincetemp)


        cn = New SqlConnection(MDBConnectString)
        cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT " &
                            "TM_Customer.CustomerNumber, " &
                            "TM_Customer.CustomerName ")

    cn.Open()


        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        Dim today As Date = Now
        Dim DasDate As Date
        Dim ErrorDescription As String = ""
        Dim IndexNumber As Integer = 0
        While dr.Read
            DasDate = dr("LastModifiedDatetime")
            If DasDate >= Daysbefore Then

                Dim DasErrorCode As String = ""
                If IsDBNull(dr("ErrorFlag")) Then
                    DasErrorCode = "None"
                Else
                    DasErrorCode = dr("ErrorFlag")
                End If



                IndexNumber = IndexNumber + 1
                gotAtLeastOne = "Y"
                itemNumber = itemNumber + 1
                drow = dt.NewRow
                drow("Index") = IndexNumber
                drow("CustomerNumber") = dr("CustomerNumber")
                drow("CustomerName") = dr("CustomerName")

                dt.Rows.Add(drow)

                daRowInfo = drow("Index") & ") *** Customer" & drow("Customer") & "-"

     End If
        End While

        cn.Close()

        If gotAtLeastOne = "Y" Then
            dt.WriteXml("c:/temp/********_" + GetNowDateAndTime() + ".xml")
        End If




    End Sub
```

Here are error details posted as well.

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized.
  Source=System.Data.SqlClient
  StackTrace:
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(Boolean async, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at *****_*_*******.Form1.MakeExportButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\****** ********\source\repos\***** * *******\***** * *******\Form1.vb:line 87
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, WM msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: Side notes: `SELECT TM_Customer.CustomerNumber, TM_Customer.CustomerName` is not a valid query. If you just want a `DataTable` consider using `DataTable.Load`. Make sure you dispose your connection, command and reader with `Using`

Comment: The following may be helpful: [SqlCommand(String, SqlConnection)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#system-data-sqlclient-sqlcommand-ctor(system-string-system-data-sqlclient-sqlconnection)), [Using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement), [Select statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: Thank you for your response @Charlieface.  I am confused about the validity of the query as the Customer Table with this information can be pulled up and shown when a query is performed through the database within visual studio.  I will dispose the connection, command, and reader with Using and see if that produces any different results.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you @user9938, I will review these documents and see if I can discover anything from them!

Comment: You need `SELECT ... FROM SomeTable`

Comment: Here's another option: [SqlCommand.Connection Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.connection?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Thank you both Charlieface and user9938.  I managed to resolve the issue.  Using the techniques that you explained Charlieface, as well as noticing that I had left out cn after  the final character following the arguments entered after the  cmd = New SqlCommand statement.  You guys are awesome, thank you so very much!